# How to change the font colour in EE cPanel?

Tags: control-panel

How to change the font colour in EE cPanel ?
I never have taken to the idea using "Grey" text instead of Black text. It seems daft spending money to buy a large monitor, and then give the text a faded look ? I have copied the CP themes folder and renamed it as my custom scheme. But I am unable to see how to edit the font colour. In the CSS file some of the values are visible and can be changed. But, for example, 'subtext' shows a size etc, in the global css file, but no options for the colour.
Can anyone help on this ? I want to change all of the light grey text to Black
I am doing this on my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this without installing or maintaining any add-ons by creating an [override.css](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_styles/#overriding-control-panel-style). You can then adjust any of the styling for any elements you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Hi might want to have a look here: [Control Panel Rebrand](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/control-panel-rebrand)

It's free too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tom's suggested theme, here's [another one (Sassy)](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sassy-cp).

Alternatively you can customise it specifically without changing any of the core files using [the CSS & JS extension](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js).